# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 in C when trying to import headers

Tags: c

this is my 'main' file.

```
/* Formats a file of text */ 

#include <string.h>
#include "line.h"
#include "word.h"

#define MAX_WORD_LEN 20

int main(void) {
    char word[MAX_WORD_LEN + 2]; 
    int word_len; 

    clear_line(); 

    while(1) {
        read_word(word, MAX_WORD_LEN + 1); 
        word_len = strlen(word); 
        if (word_len == 0) {
            flush_line(); 
            return 0; 
        }

        if (word_len > MAX_WORD_LEN) {
            word[MAX_WORD_LEN] = '*'; 
        }

        if (word_len + 1 > space_remaining()) {
            write_line(); 
            clear_line(); 
        }
        add_word(word); 
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

and, i am importing line.h and word.h files, which are

```
#ifndef WORD_H 
#define WORD_H

void read_word(char *word, int len); 

#endif
```

// this is the implementation file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "word.h"

char read_char(void) {
    char ch = getchar(); 
    if (ch == '\n' || ch == '\t') {
        return ' '; 
    }
    return ch; 
}

// What is being put in the word is the buffer. 
void read_word(char *word, int len) {
    char ch; 
    int pos = 0; 

    // continue reading until we find the first char that is not ' '. 
    while((ch = read_char()) == ' '); 

    // putting the char into the word 
    do {
        if (pos < len - 1) {
            word[pos++] = ch; 
        }
        ch = read_char(); 
    }while (ch != ' ' && ch != EOF); 
    word[pos] = '\0'; 
    printf("%s\n", word);

}
```

and

```
#ifndef LINE_H 
#define LINE_H 

// clears the current line 
void clear_line(void); 

// add words to end of the current line. If this is not the first word 
// on the line, put one space before word. 
void add_word(const char *word); 

// space remaining: returns the number of characters left in the current line. 
int space_remaining(void); 

// writes the current line with justification. 
void write_line(void);

// Writes the current line without justification. If the line is emtpy, does nothing.  
void flush_line(void); 

#endif
```

// this is the implementation file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "line.h"

#define MAX_LINE_LEN 60 

char line[MAX_LINE_LEN]; 
int line_len = 0; 
int num_words = 0; 

void clear_line(void) {
    line[0] = '\0'; 
    line_len = 0; 
    num_words = 0; 
}

void add_word(const char *word) {
    if (num_words > 0) {
        line[line_len] = ' '; 
        line[line_len + 1] = '\0'; 
        line_len++; 
    }
    strcat(line, word); 
    line_len += strlen(word); 
    num_words++; 
}

int space_remaining(void) {
    return MAX_LINE_LEN - line_len; 
}

void write_line(void) {
    int extra_spaces, spaces_to_insert; 

    extra_spaces = space_remaining(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < line_len; i++) {
        if (line[i] != ' ') {
            putchar(line[i]); 
        } else {
            spaces_to_insert = extra_spaces / (num_words - 1); 
            for (int j = 0; j < spaces_to_insert; j++) {
                putchar(' '); 
            }
            extra_spaces -= spaces_to_insert; 
            num_words--; 
        }
    }
    putchar('\n'); 
}

void flush_line(void) {
    if (line_len > 0) {
        puts(line);  
    }
}
```

I am new to C, and i am doing these using sublime editor, somehow i keep getting the following errors.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_add_word", referenced from:
      _main in justify-222ad0.o
  "_clear_line", referenced from:
      _main in justify-222ad0.o
  "_flush_line", referenced from:
      _main in justify-222ad0.o
  "_read_word", referenced from:
      _main in justify-222ad0.o
  "_space_remaining", referenced from:
      _main in justify-222ad0.o
  "_write_line", referenced from:
      _main in justify-222ad0.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

anyone knows why?

The files are in the same directory.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the command(s) you use to compile and link your program. Presumably you are not linking all modules to the executable.

Comment: @thebusybee i am using gcc justify.c command.

Comment: okay, i got u, i forgot to link the files